# get wrong-type-argument sequencep in emacs ()

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

I always get

```
Error during redisplay: (wrong-type-argument sequencep 42) [22 times]
```

in emacs **Message** buffer. whole *Message buffer* is this error message.

Even I use fundamental mode, the error still counted.

Time count happens when I Save buffer, change buffer.
  But time don't change when just simply put in characters or move
  cursors in one buffer.

What should I do to find out the root cause?
  a Better method to find out this problem conveniently ,
  just as add a --debug-init when emacs startup. At least, It can tell me which line
  raise errors.

My settings:
emacs 24.1, 24.2(currently). archlinux.

Answer (score 0):

This `Error during redisplay` means that the error is in Elisp code that is run during redisplay, so Emacs can't conveniently give you much info because that would require displaying something, and that's already what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a semi-wild guess: some of your code is trying to do something to the mode-line text, which redisplay tries to update often.  42 as a character is `*`, and a string is a sequence. Here's another semi-wild guess: some code that you load, and that tries to fiddle with the mode line,  tries to handle the *character* `*` as if it were the string `*`, performing a sequence operation on that (expected) string.

Anyway, to find the problem, bisect your init file (`~/.emacs`) recursively until you locate the culprit code. (I assume you do not have the problem when you start Emacs without your init file: `emacs -Q`.)